# ObjectID .getTimestamp() MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, time, timestamp

I was supprised to learn that `ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()` returned according to the mongodb.org website `ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z")`

So my question is if this ObjectID is it the MongoID? or are they two separate things.

The reason I ask is currently when a user post a status to our site we use time() function in PHP to store the time that the user posted the status, it would save us a little bit of code if we were able to use the mongoID to get the time and date that the status was uploaded.

I am interested in whether I am understanding this correctly.

I would also be interested in a PHP example on how I would get the MongoID to output as the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is if this ObjectID is it the MongoID?

Mongodb identifies documents by their `_id` field. If you not supply an `_id` field at insertion, the mongodb server will generate an `ObjectId` for that document (into its `_id` field). In php, these values will be converted to the `MongoId` class.

> ...  if we were able to use the mongoID to get the time and date that the status was uploaded.

Maybe. `ObjectId`s are [constructed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) using a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch. If you don't supply an `_id` field at insertion (or you supply an `ObjectId` value, generated by your client application, using [MongoDB's supplied api](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php#refsect1-mongoid.construct-examples) for that), `ObjectId`s can be used for that. But, you are not forced to use `ObjectId` at every `_id` field (or at all). Also (because they represented in 4 bytes) they are affected by the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) [...](http://www.google.hu/search?q=mongodb%20objectid%20year%202038%20problem)